# Uploadify - onComplete || onAllComplete not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I know there are already some threads with this question, but none was helpful to me.

I have an image manager and I would like to reload the page with "onComplete" event, but it not work for me.

you can see an example: http://graficnova.com/uploadifytest/imgLoader.php

Everything works successful!!, but u need press f5 key for refresh it :(.

Thx and sorry for my english!

code:

head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#fileInput").uploadify({
                width : 100,
                swf           : 'swf/uploadify.swf',
                uploader      : 'php/uploadify.php',                    
                queueID : 'imgloadList',
                oncomplete : function() {
                    alert('hello world?'); //<- THIS NOT WORK
                }
            });             
        });                 
    </script>
```

php: uploadify.php

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

//$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;


$targetPath = 'xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx';



$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];



// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {     
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1'; //<- return response
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.'; //<- return response
}
```

}

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onqueuecomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Uploadify docs, there isn't an `onComplete` event, but there is an ['onUploadComplete'](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadcomplete/) event:

> Triggered once for each file when uploading is completed whether it was successful or returned an error.  If you want to know if the upload was successful or not, it’s better to use the onUploadSuccess event or onUploadError event.

Might want to give that a try.  Or check out [`onQueueComplete`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onqueuecomplete/).

Comment: onComplete is deprecated.